# servlet or server crash when doing load test

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jmeter, load-testing

I wrote a servlet and run it on tomcat6. When there is a query sent to the specified DNS, the servlet will get information and use them to search in the database(mysql), then write some thing back. I use connection pool in the tomcat6. However, when I'm trying to do a load test on my program, I found the throughput is extremely low and many exceptions like

```
Response code: Non HTTP response code:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException Non HTTP response message: Read timed
out
  Your result:
  Team and Account info\n   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method);   at
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152);    at
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122);    at
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166); at
org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90);    at
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281);   at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92);   at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61);   at
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254);    at
org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289); at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252);  at
org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191);  at
org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300);   at
org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127); at
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715); at
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520);    at
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906);    at
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805);    at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:475);   at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:295);   at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74);  at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105);  at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094);  at
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429);  at
org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257);  at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can somebody give me some suggestions? Here is my code of servlet and this is the only Java code I use in this web project, thanks

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest req, final HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        Connection conn = null;
        DataSource ds = null;
        InitialContext ctx;
        try {
            ctx = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mysql");
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            final Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeQuery("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'; ");
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        res.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        final PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();

        try {
            final Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String teamInfo = "aa\n";
            ResultSet rs = null;
            final String info = req.getQueryString();
            final String[] sp = info.split("&");
            final String[] child0 = sp[0].split("=");
            final String[] child1 = sp[1].split("=");
            final String sqlString = "select * from tweets where timeandid=\"" + child1[1] + child0[1] + "\"";
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlString);
            rs.next();
            final String a = rs.getString(2);
            teamInfo = teamInfo + rs.getString(3) + ":" + rs.getString(4).trim() + ":" + a + "\n";
            pw.print(teamInfo);
            pw.flush();

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (final SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);

        } finally {
            System.out.println("over");
        }
        pw.close();
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many tests/threads you are creating in Jmeter ?

Comment: There is a remote instance to send load to my instance. The load is about 10 thousands or more per second

Comment: Every application has its own break-down point. After which, it will not respond to any request coming in.

Comment: I second @Ved. 10k requests/s is _a lot_. Applying rough rules of thumb, this would translate to a user base of 10M. And your code is _far_ away from being optimized. I am not even sure if your MySQL server can handle this amount of connections easily, and rather doubt it. I'd first try to optimize the code and then try load tests.

Comment: You are putting an insane amount of load without even optimizing your infra setup. It is meant to break/crash the system.

Comment: I check the log. And find that the problem is, at first the time of executing SQL statement like 'select' is quick(takes 0ms), but after there are more and more connection to the database(connection time is 20ms, all the same) the searching speed will increase. From 0 ms to 200ms, then to 5000ms! Does it mean it is the problem of database and what should I do about it? I'm pretty new in this domain. Thanks